# Configuring incomplete, errors occurred! cmake

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, build, cmakelists-options

I am not able to build.

The error:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:14 (find_package):
  Could not find a configuration file for package "Qt5" that is compatible
  with requested version "5.12".

  The following configuration files were considered but not accepted:

    /home/delta/anaconda3/lib/cmake/Qt5/Qt5Config.cmake, version: 5.9.7



-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/delta/Downloads/template-2021-master/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

Please let me know how can I solve this?

Comment: Hmm... You have installed Qt 5.9 but you want to build a software which requires Qt 5.12? ;-) _Please let me know how can I solve this?_ Either install a newer version of Qt or try to build something else (which doesn't need Qt 5.12).